# After changing menu in WordPress it gives blank page

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have problem with my wordpress website, however, I'm trying to change menus and when I make changes and then I click "Save", blank page is shown after few seconds. This menu contains a lot of menu items. However, when I try to edit a menu that contains less menu items, everything's okay.

What should I do?

Also I've found this error in my error log and have no idea how to fix them. I'm php developer by the way.

```
[25-May-2015 18:02:09 Europe/Budapest] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function send_origin_headers() in /home/gloster/public_html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php on line 25


[25-May-2015 15:09:34 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function wp_get_nav_menu_to_edit() in /home/gloster/public_html/wp-admin/nav-menus.php on line 477
```

Edit: I have found that after 17. menu item, any change to menu gives blank

Comment: blank page means syntax errors. Use error reporting. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Yes, usually, but how could I edit another menu with no problem? Also I'm using &debug=1 in url. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to php.ini variables. I increased these:

```
suhosin.post.max_vars 
suhosin.request.max_vars
```